# 'Try This' exercise on Programming Principles and Practice Using C++, For iteration

Tags: c++

I'm studying in this book (self study) and I'd really appreciate if you could help me with a little 'try this' exercise.

This is the code I wrote:

```
#include "../../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    for (char i ='a'; i <='z'; ++i) {
        int x = i;
        cout << i << '\t' << x << '\n';
    }
    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

The next step, according to the book, is: "[...] then modify your program to also write out a table of the integer values for uppercase letters and digits"
Is there a function to do that, or do I simply have to repeat the loop starting from A?
Thanks

Comment: "../../../std_lib_facilities.h" - let me guess. Schildt? No! Stroustrup. What has the world come to

Comment: Have you tried modifying your program to start from `'A'`? Did it work?

Comment: What have u tried ??post that code first.

Comment: yes i tried, it works. it writes out a table with the uppercase alphabet and the int value.
but i thought there was a better way

Comment: Hypercritical note: this isn't portable. If your system encodes characters in EBCDIC (mostly used on IBM mainframes), you'll get a bunch of extra characters between 'i' and 'j', and between 'r' and 's'; the letters of the alphabet are not contiguous in EBCDIC.

Comment: This exercise is trying to teach you how simple loops and i/o work; don't look for a function to do it for you, but try it out the long way (starting from 'A', and starting from '0')

Answer (score 3):

Yes, repeat the loop from 'A' to 'Z' and '0' to '9'.

Assuming your book has covered functions (which it may not have), you might refactor your for loop into its own function perhaps called displayCharactersInTable which takes as arguments the first character and last character.  Those would replace the use of 'a' and 'z' in the loop.  Thus your main function would look like:

```
...
displayCharactersInTable('a', 'z');
displayCharactersInTable('A', 'Z');
displayCharactersInTable('0', '9');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const char lc_alphabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
const char uc_alphabet[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

int main() {
    for (const char *cur = lc_alphabet; cur < lc_alphabet + sizeof(lc_alphabet); ++cur)
        std::cout << *cur << \t << (int)*cur << '\n';
    for (const char *cur = uc_alphabet; cur < uc_alphabet + sizeof(uc_alphabet); ++cur)
        std::cout << *cur << \t << (int)*cur << '\n';
return 0;
}
```

This code does not assume that character representations are contiguous (or even increasing alphabetically), so it will work for all character encodings.

Answer (score 0):

```
int b = 97; // the corresponding decimal ascii code for 'a'
int a = 65; // the corresponding decimal ascii code for 'A'

for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    cout << char('A' + i) << '\t' << a << '\t' << char('a' + i) << '\t' << b << '\n'; //print out 'A' and add i, print out a, print out 'a' and add i, print out b
    ++a; //increment a by 1
    ++b; //increment b by 1
```